# How use onTap function of treeview library flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, treeview, flutter-dependencies, gesturedetector

Hi I am using this pubdev package https://pub.dev/packages/tree_view/example . My problem is that when I use the onTap function the expanded does not work, I was checking the library and I noticed that it is because of this code, however I do not know how to solve it or if there is another way to access that function from the library from the widget. Any ideas [image]

If you notice it when the onTap function is different from empty, the **toggleExpanded()** function does not apply
[image]

So any ideas??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to control the expansion yourself using the [startExpanded](https://pub.dev/documentation/tree_view/latest/tree_view/TreeView/startExpanded.html) property of the [TreeView](https://pub.dev/documentation/tree_view/latest/tree_view/TreeView-class.html) widget.

First, you have a boolean variable (say `_startExpanded`) in your `StatefulWidget` that hold the state of the expansion and you can set it the default state (for instance, `false`).

```dart
bool _startExpanded = false;
```

Then, you pass the variable to your `TreeView` widget:

```dart
TreeView(
    startExpanded: _startExpanded,
    children: _getChildList(documentList),
),
```

To expand, you call:

```dart
setState((){
  _startExpanded = true;
});
```

To close, you call:

```dart
setState((){
  _startExpanded = false;
});
```